# How can I get all data via doctrine except one?

Tags: symfony, oop, doctrine, entity, findall

I am getting data via doctrine:

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
```

What I want to to is get all data, except the data with the slug `cat`

So I trying to achieve something like this:

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAllExcept(['slug'=>'cat']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good practice to use custom repository class.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\Pages
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PagesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param $slug
     * @return Pages[]
     */
    public function findAllExceptThis($slug)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('pages')
            ->andWhere('pages.slug != :slug')
            ->setParameter('slug', $slug)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This means with getDoctrine, this is not possible?

Comment: I mentioned in here https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository, repository object allows you to run basic queries.

Comment: So, I can use this object later like this? -->`$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAllExceptThis($slug);`

Comment: And you should edit Pages entity as like this @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PagesRepository")

Comment: I try to generate it, but I get the error message ` Namespace "AppBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.`

Comment: What is your bundle name?

Comment: Now I understood how to do it. I already had this repository. Now everything works!